# python xml processing - how to loop through all elements?

Tags: python, xml, django

Sorry for asking this question although there are many threads about this. But it seems, none of them is fullfilling my need now.

i have a xml file.

```
<RestaurantList>
 <Restaurant id="100000">
  <Url>http://www.example.com/</Url>
  <Name>TestRestaurant</Name>
  <Description>
   <Text>This restaurant has a generous selection of fine wines</Text>
  </Description>
 </Restaurant>
 <Restaurant id="100001">
  <Url>http://www.example.com/</Url>
  <Name>TestRestaurant1</Name>
  <Description>
   <Text>This restaurant1 has a generous selection of fine wines</Text>
  </Description>
 </Restaurant>
</RestaurantList>
```

i want to loop over all elements and take some of them and save into db. I saw some libraries like `lxml` or `xml` in python. And I tried this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
file = ET.parse(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'\\table.xml')
    rests = file.xpath('//Restaurant')
    for each in rests:
        self.stdout.write(each)
```

but I am getting `ElementTree has no object attribute xpath` error,

what is the best way of doing this? thanks in tons in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code works for me perfectly with Python 2.7.4 and lxml 3.2.3, the `xpath()` method returning a list containing the two `Restaurant` elements. If your XML parser insists that the XML file is well-formed, maybe you are giving it the wrong file, or the file is saved in a non-recognized encoding such as UTF-16.

To debug this, try printing `open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'\\table.xml').read()` and see if the output looks like valid XML. If in doubt about the correctness of XML, it's a good idea to also verify it using an independent tool such as [`xmllint`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/xmldtd.html#validate1).

Comment: sorry, i was getting another error message. can you please take a look again?

Comment: @doniyor The error message tells you that ElementTree doesn't support `xpath`. As I said, I tested your code with lxml (more precisely with `import lxml.etree as ET`), and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got it by doing so:

```
datei = ET.parse(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'\\table.xml')
    rests = datei.getroot()
    for each in rests:
      #do something with tags
```

thanks anyway for answers and views..